# A Tour of Go #23: weird behaviour with return

Tags: go

[A Tour of Go #23](http://tour.golang.org/#23):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func pow(x, n, lim float64) float64 {
    if v := math.Pow(x, n); v < lim {
        return v

    } else {
        fmt.Printf("%g >= %g\n", v, lim)
    }
    // can't use v here, though
    return lim
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(
        pow(3, 2, 10),
        pow(3, 3, 20),
    )
}
```

The results are:

```
27 >= 20
9 20
```

If I comment out the `return v` line, the results are:

```
27 >= 20
10 20
```

Why exactly does this happen? Why are results of the first `pow()` call not equal to `27 >= 20` and `10`?

Comment: Because in the first `pow` call, `lim==10` instead of `20`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already answered by @larsmans, you're passing a limit of 10 to the first call, thus 
the returned number is 10 instead of 20.

Change it to

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println(
        pow(3, 2, 20),
        pow(3, 3, 20),
    )
}
```

And you will see the following output when removing the `return v` line:

```
27 >= 20
20 20
```

Comment: I know that. The thing I don't know is why it doesn't return `10` the first time `pow()` is called.

Comment: Without you removing `return v`? Because in this case `v` (9) is smaller than `lim` (10) and therefore `v` is returned, which is 9. According to the line `if v := math.Pow(x, n); v < lim {` this seems to be correct for me.

Comment: Oooh, I get it now. The whole time I was doing multiplication in my mind instead of exponentiation, that's why I had hard time getting it ;)